# Is the Kleene Star $*$ distributive over concatenation?

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

I'm currently learning about automata theory and I came across the following question:

Given an arbitrary set $L$ of symbols. Is $(L \: \cdot \: L)$* = $L$* $\cdot$ $L$* true, where * refers to the Kleene star and $\cdot$ to concatenation?

I've already read in other questions, that $(L_1 \: \cdot \: L_2)$* = $L_1$* $\cdot$ $L_2$* is not true, however what happens when $L_1 = L_2$ as in this case. I feel like if its the same set then it should be true, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. If $A$ is the alphabet, $(AA)^*$ is the set of words of even length.
Now, what is $A^*A^*$?

Comment: $A$*$A$* would still be $A$* as far as I understand it and that is not equal to the set of words of even length.

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick help.

Comment: Would it however still be false, if $L$ was a formal language, as in $L \subseteq A$*?

Comment: If I am not wrong, the equality $(LL)^* = L^*L^*$ holds if and only if $L$ contains the empty word. This could be the topic of a separate question.